# difference between ways to generate index list in python

Tags: python, indexing

I am reading Joel Grus's data science from scratch book and found something a bit mysterious. Basically, in some sample code, he wrote

```
a = [1, 2 ,3 ,4]
xs = [i for i,_ in enumerate(a)]
```

Why would he prefer to do this way? Instead of

```
xs = range(len(a))
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Range is more readable than enumerate and avoids the uneccessary generated index...

Comment: this just looks like he doesn't know what he is doing TBH. an extra throwaway variable, and throwing away the *only* extra thing enumerate gets you?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer: personal preference of the author. I find

`[i for i, _ in enumerate(xs)]`

clearer and more readable than

`list(range(len(xs)))`

which feels clunky to me. (I don't like reading the nested functions.) Your mileage may vary (and apparently does!).

That said, I am pretty sure I didn't say *not to* do the second, I just happen to prefer the first.

Source: I am the author.

P.S. If you're the commenter who had no intention of reading **anything** I write about Python, I apologize if you read this answer by accident.

Comment: I guess the list comp with `enumerate` _is_ a little clearer to read than the triply nested function call... but I _still_ don't like it. ;)

Comment: Perhaps my saying that I have no intention of reading anything you write about Python _was_ a bit extreme. And although I don't like your your list comp, I guess it _is_ Pythonic, since "Flat is better than nested". OTOH, "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it". :)

Answer (score 8):

I looked at [the code available on github](https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch) and frankly, I do not see any other reason for this except the personal preference of the author.

However, the result needs to be a `list` in places like [this](https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch/blob/2d4063dbcb19953bcd3f1d488cb148beb4911d14/code-python3/gradient_descent.py#L110):

```
indexes = [i for i, _ in enumerate(data)]  # create a list of indexes
random.shuffle(indexes)                    # shuffle them
for i in indexes:                          # return the data in that order
    yield data[i]
```

Using bare `range(len(data))` in that part on Python 3 would be wrong, because `random.shuffle()` requires *a mutable sequence* as the argument, and the `range` objects in Python 3 are immutable sequences.

---

I personally would use `list(range(len(data)))` on Python 3 in the case that I linked to, as it is guaranteed to be more efficient **and** would fail if a generator/iterator was passed in by accident, instead of a sequence.

Comment: Nice point about `len` raising an error (`TypeError`) if `data` isn't a valid arg for it.

Answer (score 2):

Without being the author, I would have to guess, but my guess is that it's for Python 2 and 3 compatibility.

In Python 2:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> xs = range(len(a))
>>> xs
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> type(xs)
<type 'list'>
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> xs = range(len(a))
>>> xs
range(0, 4)
>>> type(xs)
<class 'range'>
```

Now, that doesn't make a difference when you're directly iterating over the `range`, but if you're planning to use the index list for something else later on, the author may feel that the enumerate is simpler to understand than `list(range(len(a)))`

Comment: If the author feels that the enumerate is simpler to understand than `list(range(len(a)))` I have no intention of reading **anything** he writes about Python! Sure, `list(range(len(a)))` is _slightly_ inefficient in Python 2, but both those calls run at C speed so it's still pretty fast, and for large `len(a)` it will be much faster than the Python speed loop in a list comp using enumerate (or range or xrange).

Comment: I've not read the book, but it may also be a poor choice of syllabus ordering, too - if the book hasn't introduced the `range` statement, but has introduced `enumerate`, that might be a reason. Mind you, even if that's true, it's better to introduce `range`

Answer (score -2):

Both are ok.
When I started coding in python I was more list(range(len(a))) .
Now I am more in [pythonic way](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#index-item-2) .
Both are readable.

Comment: Sure, `range(len(a))` _can_ often be a symptom of un-Pythonic code. And one _should_ often use `enumerate` instead. But in this case, `list(range(len(a)))` is more Pythonic than that list comp in the OP.

Comment: I dont think range(len(a)) is unpythonic.
And I really like list comprehension solution.

Comment: I didn't say that `range(len(a))` is unpythonic, I said it can often be a symptom of un-Pythonic code. That's because it's often used to indirectly iterate over a list, IOW, to iterate via the index, rather than to iterate directly over the list items. Generally, it's better to iterate directly, and if you _also_ need the index then you should use `enumerate`. But to use `enumerate` simply to get the index when you don't want the list items is just plain weird, IMHO.

Comment: (cont) Antti Happala's answer explains why `list(range(len(data)))` is better here (or just `range(len(data))` on Python 2 if you don't care about Python 3 compatibility).

Comment: "I personally would use list(range(len(data)))" this is not an explaination, but a personnal choice.

I find personnaly find [index for index,_ in enumerate(lst)] really easy to read and I dont clain it is the only way to do it. 

reason (still personnal preference):

Comment: "as it is guaranteed to be more efficient and would fail if a generator/iterator was passed in by accident, instead of a sequence" **is** an explanation for that preference.

Comment: reason (still personnal preference):
- it is readable like dumb english, "index for index in enumerate lst"
- it look a like math { index | index E enum(lst) }
- and i look like SQL : SELECT rownumber() as index FROM lst
- with experience i found less productive to do list(range(len(... than
    length = len(lst)
    enum = range(length)
    result = list(enum)